# Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

After WSO2 Identity server migration to 5.3.0 , the following messages are printed in the log.
The start up is very slow because of this as well.

```
[2018-05-01 05:53:04,802]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,

[2018-05-01 05:54:04,802]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,

[2018-05-01 05:55:04,802]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,


[2018-05-01 05:56:04,802]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,
```

How can i find what is missing?Did i miss some configuration while migrating?

Answer (score 1):

This message get printed due to a background process running during the migration. (In the background token related migration is happening). If you have huge amount of old tokens (expired, etc), then this process would take some time.

We have documented this case in API Manager 2.0.0 migration docs as well (there is an Identity server migration in AM 2.0.0 migration). See point 10 in "Upgrading the API Manager to 2.0.0" section in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release (Warning is not exactly same. but similar)

Please note that stopping in the mid-migration would cause corruption in the database.

Comment: Is there a table which i can check for the tokens?
Also I am upgrading WSO2 Identity server first ..Migrate it and start it..
Then I am doing the WSO2 API Manager...
Is that the right order to do it?
Or should i be starting both togother?I was hoping to migrate id server first and if its good ,I can go for migrating API Manager.

Comment: Do i supposed to get the error message even if i am not running the migration?